# How to increase maximum connection backlog limit in windows server

Tags: tcp, websocket, connection

I have a Windows Server. Its maximum connection backlog limit (TCP) is 100.

Is there any way to increase this limit to a higher value – say 1000 or 2000?

I changed the Registry under this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AFD\Parameters 
TcpNumConnections: DWORD 0x00fffffe
MaxHashTableSize: DWORD 0xffff
MaxFreeTcbs: DWORD 0xffffffff
TcpMaxHalfOpen: DWORD 0xffff
```

But, no matter what I do, I am still limited to a backlog of 100 connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try setting the `EnableDynamicBacklog`, `MinimumDynamicBacklog`, and `MaximumDynamicBacklog` values in that same Registry key? See [Optimizing Network Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc558565.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: I didn't set it to these，I'll try to set these

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? You haven't tried them yet? You don't see them so you can set them? If they don't exist, just add them.

Comment: I set these still can not

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  You can't set them at all?  Or you set them but they don't affect the backlog? Did you reboot after changing them?

Comment: I set them at all，and reboot after changing them,it still limited to a backlog of 100 connections.
I found that when the number of connections reached 100, the client's request was not submitted to the server.

Comment: An interesting find - your question is almost a word-for-word copy of [another question asked 7 years ago on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/113288/).